# Android espresso console log Build.Serial onFail

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing, android-espresso

I am running test on multiple devices at once using the adb test command. My pseudo shell script looks like this:

```
for each device
   adb -s ${device} shell am instrument -w -e ${classOrPkg} ${androidTestPackage}${test_name} ${main_package}.${flavor}.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner &
```

The problem is when a test fails, I have no information on which device the failure occurred. I could use LogCat but it requires looking up logcat for each device. And also, System.out.println() does not work.

One possible solution I am trying right now is by extending TestWatcher class and overriding the failed() method like this,

```
public class TestWatcherRule extends TestWatcher {
    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
        Description d = Description.createTestDescription(e.getClass(), "<<<< Failed on Device: " + Build.SERIAL);
        super.failed(e, d);
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
@Rule
public TestWatcher testWatcher = new TestWatcherRule();
assertThat("My message", true, is(false));
```

I cannot get the device serial yet on the terminal.

My expected output would be something like this:

```
com.myapp.mobile.tests.BenefitCardDBTest:
Error in addDeleteCard(com.myapp.mobile.tests.BenefitCardDBTest):
**<<<< Failed on Device: HTC10xwrtxe**
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: com.myapp.mobile.qa:id/drawer_layout
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say this is my sample `Espresso` test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class SettingsActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<SettingsActivity> mRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(SettingsActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void checkIfToolbarIsProperlyDisplayed() throws InterruptedException {
        onView(withText(R.string.action_settings)).check(matches(withParent(withId(R.id.toolbar))));
        onView(withId(R.id.toolbar)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

To run it on multiple devices I'm using `Gradle`'s `connectedAndroidTest` which extends `connectedCheck`, so it :

> will run on all connected devices in parallel.
>
> From:
>   http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Android-tasks

Just go use your terminal or console to go to your project's directory, then use:

`./gradlew connectedAndroidTest`.

This one is very useful as it would generate HTML test output which allows you to check which method on which device had failed.

It would look like this:

[image: *emphasized text*]

Hope it will help

Comment: Thank you for the response. I forgot to mention that I am aware of running tests this way by using gradle task. The only problem is that the tests don't run immediately, i.e., gradle builds, install apks, runs tests and uninstalls apk. I like the adb command since it will run tests instantly. Do you know a way to skip the build part and just run the tests using gradle connectedCheck command?

Comment: I don't know as much Gradle, but try to find which commands are `connectedAndroidTest` or `connectedCheck` using. Maybe `./gradlew test` would skip building